# A numerical rebus

Tags: rebus

What does this rebus mean?

```
1T3456789
```

Comment: Everything that's coming to mind is golf related or video game related.

Comment: @Emrakul - looks like OP hasn't visited the site since the answers were posted. It's possible (and likely) that the most popular answer is correct. I'm guessing had OP been back to mark it correct, you wouldn't have put the question on hold?

Comment: @TTT I still think it's too broad, regardless; while the top answer may be correct, the other answers make it clear (to me, at least? I could be wrong) that there are a large number of other plausible answers as well.

Comment: @Emrakul The top answer is the only one that can be wholly justified by what's in the actual puzzle - all the others require other information that would have been trivial to add if any of them were applicable (and only one of those other answers is a) not a duplicate and b) a "common phrase")

Comment: I feel that if this warranted closing in the first place, it should have had something added as to the topic or nature of the intended answer before being reopened. As it is, there is nothing saying it should be a "common phrase" or even that it is a phrase at all.  I don't think we ought to condone a 10-character puzzle described only by a tag and what amounts to "Answer it".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Is it

> tea for two?

Comment: I would guess: at --> for

Answer (score 13):

If the T means

> Tango (as in [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet))

It could be

> (it takes) two to tango

Answer (score 3):

> Two to ten

I'm assuming a notational convention often used for

> card games.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can come up with on this one is:

> 2 o'clock tee time or tee off at 2

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> One second later

because

> letter pronounced as later

Answer (score 1):

> Tea at 2 
>  The T is in place of where 2 normally be. (Interpreted as Tea at 2pm)

Answer (score -1):

> one "T" **in**  "1**T**345679"  and **in**  "one **t**hree four five six seven eight nine"  
>  Note: there are  **two** "T"'s (or "t") **in** "one **T**ee **t**hree four five six seven eight nine" but this doesn't "play" on the semiotics of the syntax behind the pun's semantics

Comment: Can you give reasoning?

Comment: You missed the 'T' in "eigh**T**".