# Is there a cryptic crossword clue that doesn't contain any actual word?

Tags: cryptic-clues, crossword-clues

Is there a cryptic crossword clue that just contains some letter groups, numbers, and other things, but no actual words?
I mean the clue, not the solution.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but the answer that hexomino just gave isn't [cryptic](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide). There's no definition for the phrase.

Answer (score 6):

There was such a Clue in the Independent (I think)
The Clue was:

> 0.9

The answer is:

> NIX.(0 is the def. .=point=Compass point=N(for north) and 9=IX)

You can also slightly change the clue to make it,

> 6.9

For this the answer is the obvious:

> SIX  (Same as above with a changed def and a different compass point)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

> 1T3456789 (3,3,3) 
>  which is an adaptation of a puzzle already on this site: [A numerical rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29738/a-numerical-rebus)

I think, in general, you could

> Use a rebus which can be typed out as the clue. I think this still qualifies it as being cryptic.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but the clue isn't [cryptic](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide). Pay attention to the tag.

Comment: I think this answers the question as yes, these types of cryptic clue are published. For example, one from the Guardian Weekly was: N + 1 = 0 (4)

Comment: @Tom maybe yours is a better answer as it sort of contains two definitions which is possibly what my one lacks.

Comment: @Tom , I think the answer is "none". (N + one = none)

Answer (score 2):

There's another example that's so good and so evil that it deserves an answer of its own. This clue is a Puzzling original and was created by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi).
Here's a link to the clue itself:  [One of Deusovi's most evil clues](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=34991974#34991974).

For those of you too lazy to click a link, here's the clue itself:

> 000-ish

The answer is:

> Ovoid. (O+Void)

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a whole [crossword](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80777/emojional-cryptic-crossword) with [emoji](/questions/tagged/emoji)s, and the clues *indeed* don't contain any words.
2. Another emoji [crossword](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90688/emojional-cryptics-slight-return).

Comment: I made an update