# Emojional cryptic crossword

Tags: knowledge, visual, language, geography, cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **ACROSS**
>   3. ½☥ (9)
>   7. ❌⚔️ (3)
>   8. ½ (6)
>   11. ♉½✉️ (3)
>   12. ⭐⏺️♥️ (5)
>   13. ♥️️⏮️ (6)
>   14. ♀️ (5)
>   16. ♻️☝️️ (6)
>   19.  (3)
>   20. ⛔️➖ (7)
>   21.  (7)
>   22.  (6)
>
> **DOWN**
>   1. ️️ (6)
>   2. ✈️ (6)
>   4.  (7)
>   5. ️☝️☂️ (5)
>   6. ️✂️♥️ (6)
>   9. ∨◀️⛔☿️♥️ (7)
>   10. ☝️½ (3)
>   15.  (5)
>   17. ❌ (4)
>   18. ❌☝️‍↩️ (5)

Note: If you're seeing capital letters in some of the clues (e.g. "FR" in 8a), those are supposed to be flags of countries. Apparently some environments don't support flag emojis. I get flags on mobile, but letters on desktop.

Image version to avoid compatibility issues:

> [image]

Comment: Some of these emojis show just empty boxes to me...

Comment: @Sid I've added an image version of the clues.

Comment: @jafe I can't view the picture. Maybe use Photobucket?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Across:

12 ⭐⏺️♥️ (5)

> Shooting star: heart of record (Thanks, @JonMark Perry!) (CO) + New York art (MET) = **COMET**.

13 ♥️️⏮️ (6)

> Flowers: Heart of Melon (L) + Cali backwards (ILAC) end of fries (S) = **LILACS**.

14♀️ (5)

> Sounds like a female deer and means money = **DOUGH**.

16 ♻️☝️️ (6)

> Japanese island: Nosh rearranged (HONS) Horse Unicorn first (HU) = **HONSHU**.

19  (3)

> Arm mixed up = **RAM**.

20 ⛔️➖ (7)

> Punching: (BAT) + tie - I (TE) + cry - 100 (C in Roman numerals) (RY) = **BATTERY**.

21  (7)

> Singing music: Karate - ET (KARA) + OK + end of eagle (E) = **KARAOKE**.

22  (6)

> Glasses clinking and people celebrating = **CHEERS**.

Down:

5 ️☝️☂️ (5)

> City: not sure Russia last three? (DAE) + heart of egg (G) + first of umbrella (U) = **DAEGU**.

9 ∨◀️⛔☿️♥️ (7)

> Chicken: Or inverted (RO) + ghost - mercury (GHOST - HG = OST) + heart of Fern (ER) = **ROOSTER**.

10 ☝️½ (3)

> Bird: top of eggplant (E) + 1/2 of mute (MU) = **EMU**.

15  (5)

> Month: night music = **MARCH**.

17 ❌ (4)

> Horn: Robot without exterior (OBO) + end of horse (E) = **OBOE**.

18 ❌☝️‍↩️ (5)

> No clothes: first letter of Koala (K) inside dean reversed (NA_ED) = **NAKED**.

Final crossword, with much thanks to @pirate for answers and decryptions! Please upvote their answer:

> [image: Emoji Cryptic]

Comment: 13 is heart of rot13(zryba)

Comment: 12 is heart of rot12(dqoadp) - rot14(me uz ftq aftqd nxgq uoaze)

Comment: Thanks, @JonMarkPerry! Greatly appreciated...although why rot12/14??

Comment: I thought I'd be different :)

Answer (score 10):

Partial:

Across:

3 ½☥ (9)

> 1/2 of Ankh (An) + Dromedary - ry (last 2 letters) = **Andromeda** (Galaxy)

7 ❌⚔️ (3)

> <strike>A</strike>war<strike>d</strike> = **War**

8 ½ (6)

> 1/2 of burger (Bur) + Water in French (Eau) = **Bureau**

11 ♉½✉️ (3)

> Zodiac sign and greek letter = **Tau**

16 ♻️☝️️ (6)

> Head of Hat (H) + son rearranged (ONS) + top of horse (H) + top of unicorn (U) = Honshu (island in Japan)

Down:

1 ️️ (6)

> Rearranged o+satan = **Sonata**

2 ✈️ (6)

> Air + Bus = **Airbus**

4  (7)

> Rearranged Chad + Ram = **Drachma** (Greek currency)

5 ️☝️☂️ (5)

> Russian "Yes" (Da) + e(g)g + top of umbrella (u) = **Daegu** (City in South Korea)

6 ️✂️♥️ (6)

> Au (Gold medal) + T (tee shirt) + horn - pa(n)da = **Author**