# Emojional cryptics (slight return)

Tags: knowledge, visual, cryptic-clues, emoji

> [image]

The final answer is the name of a country.

Comment: This is unsolvable with Chrome on OS X, but the brokenness is so subtle, that you can't really tell without looking at the solution or the image version.

Comment: @Bass Ugh, that's terrible. Changed it to image only to avoid technical issues.

Comment: @Bass Out of curiosity, what was the difference?

Comment: [Here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/d0wJju6.png). See those squares at 1, 13 and 14? They're probably supposed to mean "couldn't find that emoji in this font", but they blend in pretty well.

Comment: Oops, you've missed Mauritania.

Comment: I can't see the image.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The country is ...

> ... **Jamaica**.

Solutions to the cryptic clues:

> 1. **CHECKERED** — CHECK + E(-mail) + RED
>  2. **POLE** — ddef: man from Pland; fishing rod
>  3. **RAINBOW** — BRAIN* + OW(l) - tu(L)ip
>  4. **LINK** — (snai)L end + INK from squid
>  5. **BEAT** — B (bee) + (m)EAT without top
>  6. **PERSONS** — PE(a)R + SONS
>  7. **TAPE** — T(emperature) + APE
>  8. **HERRING** — HER (belongig to a woman) RING
>  9. **CROSS** — Hidden in la_CROSS_e
>  10. **SNOW** — S(nake) top + WON<
>  11. **HOUSE** — ddef: Doctor on TV, building
>  12. **LIE** — LI(k)E - K(iss)
>  13. **WHALE** — W(atc)H frame + ALE
>  14. **MOON** — MOO (cow sound) + (he)N leg
>  15. **JEANS** — sounds like (ear) "genes"

Now ...

> ... we can associate three consecutive answers with a common word:
>
>  **FLAG** — checkered flag, flagpole, rainbow flag
>  **MISSING** — missing link, missing a beat, missing persons
>  **RED** — red tape, red herrng, Red Cross
>  **WHITE** — Snow White, White House, white lie
>  **BLUE** — blue whale, (once in a) blue moon, blue jeans

We are looking for ...

> ... a country whose flag is missing red, white and blue. Jamaica's flag has black, green and yellow.

Comment: Oops, you've missed Mauritania.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat: No, not with the [current design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Mauritania).

Comment: I can't access Wikipedia.

Comment: Look [here](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/mr.html) then. Or start from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mauretania+new+flag). Saying "I can't access Wikipedia" as part of a smarty-pants discussion you've brought up yourself is not much different from tapping your ears and saying: La, la, la, I don't hear you.